# Trying to average the results of a count which is grouped?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, subquery

I am using MySQL and am trying to create a query to solve this question:

Average number of borrowed books by occupation

My plan was to count the number of instances of 'BorrowID' because each time a book is borrowed it creates a unique BorrowID. Then group those by clientID so that each person has their total listed books borrowed. Then this is where I start to get lost, as I obviously want to average all the grouped occupations however I am not sure if I am doing that...

First I tried:

```sql
SELECT client.Occupation, AVG(BorrowIDCount)
FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(BorrowID) as BorrowIDCount
    FROM client, borrower
    WHERE client.ClientID = borrower.ClientID
    GROUP BY borrower.ClientID
    ) as x
GROUP BY Occupation
```

But it gives the error:

```text
Unknown column 'client.Occupation' in 'field list'
```

Which I thought was because the outer query needed to know which tables...

So then I tried:

```sql
SELECT client.Occupation, AVG(BorrowIDCount)
FROM client, borrower
WHERE client.ClientID = borrower.ClientID AND
    (
    SELECT COUNT(BorrowID) as BorrowIDCount
    FROM client, borrower
    WHERE client.ClientID = borrower.ClientID
    GROUP BY borrower.ClientID
)
GROUP BY Occupation
```

It didn't like the alias for the subquery so I removed it although no idea why, however it then gave this error:

```text
Unknown column 'BorrowIDCount' in 'field list'
```

I feel like I may be completely off base in terms of how to create this query but I also feel that I might be close and am just not understanding some rules or syntax here. Any help in the right direction would be incredibly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to figure out the number of books borrowed by client, then to average that number by occupation. So let's do it in steps:

First is a subquery to get the books per client.

```sql
                    SELECT COUNT(*) borrowed, ClientID
                      FROM borrower
                     GROUP BY ClientID
```

Next, we use that subquery in an outer query to get the average you want.

```sql
SELECT AVG(byclient.borrowed) average_borrowed,
       client.Occupation
  FROM (
                    SELECT COUNT(*) borrowed, ClientID
                      FROM borrower
                     GROUP BY ClientID
       ) byclient
  LEFT JOIN client ON byclient.ClientID = client.ClientID
 GROUP BY client.Occupation
 ORDER BY AVG(byclient.borrowed) DESC, client.Occupation;
```

Your requirement calls for an aggregate of an aggregate, so you must nest one aggregate query inside another.

LEFT JOIN allows the inclusion of clients without any occupation. If you don't want that just use JOIN.

The first query in your question failed because your FROM clause referred to a subquery (a virtual table) that lacks the `Occupation` column.  The second one failed because `AND (virtual table)` doesn't mean anything in SQL.

This nesting of virtual tables is the **S**tructured part of **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage.

Comment: I really appreciate the step by step breakdown and the additional insight into why my own attempts didn't work. So it seems my primary issues were not referencing the sub-query (virtual table as you said) in my outer query, and not understanding/using the right syntax for joining the tables.

Thank you for your help. I hate to admit it but I had been stuck working on this for several hours. It's very gratifying when you do find a solution and the results look just how you want them to though!

Comment: Yeah, I've spent many a hour of frustration trying to get this kind of stuff to work myself. SQL is just conceptually different enough from other programming languages to drive ya nuts. I promise, you didn't waste those hours, at least not all of them :-)